# PHP form not sending me emails

Tags: php, email, send

Im having a rough time creating a php form that can email me the user input.

Ive left out the dropdown menu sections for the php code for now until i can get the basic stuff working such as the name email and phone number.

Can anyone please take a look and let me know what im doing wrong.  I am not receiving any emails after submitting.

heres the link to the exact page.
cakesbysena.com/form.php

```
<?php
  // if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $info = $_POST['info'];
    $to = 'sena@cakesbysena.com';
    $subject = 'New Order';
    $body = "<html>
              <body>
                <h1>New Order</h1>
                <hr>
                <p>Name: <br>.$name</p>
                <p>email: <br>.$email</p>
                <p>Phone: <br>.$tel</p>
                <p>Message:  <br>.$info</p>
              </body>
            </html>";

    $headers  = "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME- Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset-utf-8";

    $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    if ($send) {
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'Thanks get back to you soon.';
    } else {
        echo 'error';
    }
    }
?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Siparis</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="./images/logo.png">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel|IM+Fell+French+Canon+SC|Alice|Italiana|Sacramento|Tangerine" rel="stylesheet">

</head>




<body>

  <!-- BACKGROUND IMAGE -->
  <div class="bgimg"></div>
  <!-- NAV -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index"> Cakes by Sena <img src="./images/logo.png"  class="navlogo d-none d-md-inline d-lg-inline d-xl-inline" alt="responsive image"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon text-align-right"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="./index">Anasayfa <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="./products">Ürünler</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.instagram.com/cakesbysena/">Galeri</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="./aboutus">Hikayemiz</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- HEADER -->
  <header class="container text-center">
    <h1 class="display-3">Siparis</h1>
    <hr>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label>Ad</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Ad/Soyad">
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email Adresi</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="name@example.com">
        <small class="text-muted">Email adresiniz kimse ile paylasilmayacaktir</small>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label>Telefon Numarasi</label>
        <input type="tel" name="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="___-___-____">
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleSelect1">Siparis Turu</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1" placeholder="select">
          <option>Kurabiye</option>
          <option>Pasta</option>
          <option>Cupcake</option>
          <option>Tuzlular</option>
          <option>Ozel siparis</option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleSelect1">Kisi Sayisi</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1" placeholder="select">
          <option>6 - 8</option>
          <option>10 - 12</option>
          <option>20 + </option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleTextarea">Bize iletmek istediginiz ozel not</label>
        <textarea type="text" name="info" class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3"></textarea>
      </fieldset>
      <!-- <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">Fotograf Yukle</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleInputFile go">
        <small class="text-muted">Have an idea? Share an example of the custom order you'd like.</small>
      </fieldset> -->
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Gonder</button>
    </form>
  </header>

  <footer>

  </footer>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you send mails at all via PHP?

Comment: I haven't been successful at sending or receiving any emails.  I've tried a different email types as well.